# Difference Between downcase and downcase! in Ruby

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

I am just learning Ruby and I don't quite understand the difference between several Ruby methods with and without a '!' at the end.  What's the difference?  Why would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Methods with an exclamation mark at the end are often called bang-methods. A bang method doesn't necessarily modify its receiver as well as there is no guarantee that methods without a exclamation mark doesn't.

It's all very well explained in [this blog post](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist). To quote the post:

> The ! in method names that end with !
>   means, “This method is dangerous”—or,
>   more precisely, this method is the
>   “dangerous” version of an otherwise
>   equivalent method, with the same name
>   minus the !. “Danger” is relative; the
>   ! doesn’t mean anything at all unless
>   the method name it’s in corresponds to
>   a similar but bang-less method name.

and

> The ! does not mean “This method
>   changes its receiver.” A lot of
>   “dangerous” methods do change their
>   receivers. But some don’t. I repeat: !
>   does not mean that the method changes
>   its receiver.

Answer (score 14):

The non-bang downcase() method simply returns a new object representing you string downcased.

The bang version modifies your string itself.

```
my_text = "MY TEXT"
my_new_text = my_text.downcase
puts my_new_text # will print out "my text"
puts my_text     # will print out "MY TEXT" - the non-bang method doesn't touch it

my_text.downcase!

puts my_text # will print out "my text". The bang version has modified the object you're calling the method on
```