# Is Fixnum's power! method potentially dangerous?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions, fixnum

Why is the `power!` method in Ruby's `Fixnum` class named with an exclamation mark?  By convention, methods that have a name ending in an ! are potentially dangerous (for example, they may modify the instance in some way).

I can appreciate the difference between `gsub` and `gsub!` in `String`, but what's up with `power!`?  It doesn't seem to modify the `Fixnum` instance or perform any other "dangerous" actions; it just returns the result.

Comment: Bang methods mean danger, not necessarily modification. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709229/difference-between-downcase-and-downcase-in-ruby (I'll remove the downvote once this is fixed)

Comment: The Ruby web site (ruby-lang.org) links to a tutorial that states specifically that bang methods modify the receiver: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/writing_own_ruby_methods.html. "Ruby methods that modify an object in-place and end in an exclamation mark are known as bang methods."  So... who's right?

Comment: Ouch. However, it later says "Normally for the built-in classes, dangerous usually (although not always) means this method, unlike its non-bang equivalent, permanently modifies its receiver.". I'll reverse my downvote if you provide a blank edit to the question (I can't undo my downvote otherwise)

Comment: I took the middle road, since I have no clue who is right.  I guess it's a convention where "danger" could be anything.  Yet, in the built-in classes, it's only thus far been used in cases of receiver modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an inconsistency in the API. Nothing to worry about, move along :)

The `!` is [just a convention](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist) for destructive methods, not a rule.