# How do I define a setter for a property whose name ends with a question mark?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to add a property called "enabled?" to a model with both a getter and a setter.  However, when I do the following:

```
def enabled?= value
  # .. logic goes here ..
end
```

I get `syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting '\n' or ';'`

What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Don't use punctuation in variable names.

Comment: @DanDan: Using ? for boolean getters is the standard in ruby and not doing it would be quite unidiomatic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, ruby syntax only allows `?` in method names if it's the last character, so `foo?=` is not valid. One thing you could do, that would be pretty idiomatic, is to define `enabled?`, `enable` and `disable` (or `enable!` and `disable!` if you want to emphasize that they're mutating methods).

If that doesn't fit your needs, you can just name the methods `enabled?` and `enabled=` and just live with the slight incosistency between the names.

Comment: Information on what exclamation marks usually mean are described in [
Difference Between downcase and downcase! in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709229/difference-between-downcase-and-downcase-in-ruby/709271)

Answer (score 7):

A method name in ruby starts with a lower case letter or underscore optionally followed by upper and lower case letters underscores and digts. A method name may optionally end with a question mark, exclamation mark or equals sign.

So you can't!

You could follow the usual ruby idiom of defining enabled as follow :-

```
def enabled?
  @enabled
end

def enabled=(value)
  @enabled = value
end
```

To summarise. If you want to expose properties to the outside world then ensure your variable name will allow that within the confines of the rules for method names.

Answer (score 1):

One small variation would be to alias the getter method, allowing both `enabled` and `enabled?`:

```
def enabled
  @enabled
end

def enabled=(value)
  @enabled = value
end

alias_method :enabled?, :enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Name your property just `enabled`

The query methods are just syntactic sugar, they are not mean to be used as properties or instance variables. You can add the method `enabled?` for syntactic sugar if you wish too.

Answer (score 0):

I always name my boolean variables to start with 'is', as in 'isEnabled'. Then it has the same meaning as having the question mark w/o the need for complexity.

Comment: It would be better to follow the ruby / rails standards (does not seem 'complex' to me - just ? at end).  Otherwise code that is shared with other developers will be hard to read as the reader/maintainer will now have to use your approach for the code rather than the standard or just use both which is even worse.  I used to do this myself with _yn at the end until I learned better

Comment: Always use the standards. Join a band if you want to go your own way.