# what is the difference between exit and exit! in ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between exit and exit! in ruby?

Comment: Are you familiar with bang methods in Ruby? If not, you may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709229/difference-between-downcase-and-downcase-in-ruby

Comment: I've just found a really nice an exhaustive article: http://www.sitepoint.com/exit-exit-abort-raise-get-me-outta-here/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Couple things:

1. Exit handlers get run in the "exit" form but not "exit!".  This means any code that is assigned to "clean-up" won't get run using "exit!"
2. The "exit status" is default set to false in the "exit!" form, whereas it is true in the "exit" form. The "exit status" is a message to the operating system about the program that is stopping execution.

they are both Kernel methods: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html

Comment: Ah, thanks I see.

This might not be the best thing to do, but is there a way, I can reset the "exit status" to true for exit! as well ?

I am taking a look at the docs too.

Comment: Yep, found it, its exit!(true). Thanks.