# What is the difference between exit and abort?

Tags: ruby, exit

The [`abort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-abort) documentation says  `abort` will

> Terminate execution immediately, effectively by calling Kernel.exit(false).

What exactly does "immediately" mean? What is the difference between `abort` and `exit` with non-`true` status?

Comment: One useful post is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295394/what-is-the-difference-between-exit-and-exit-in-ruby

Answer (score 67, accepted):

"[Exit, Exit! Abort, Raise…Get Me Outta Here!](http://www.sitepoint.com/exit-exit-abort-raise-get-me-outta-here/)" describes everything you'd want to know I think.

In short:

- [`Kernel.exit(code)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) "exits" the script immediately and returns the `code` to the OS, however, just before doing it, it calls any registered `at_exit` handler that your code could have registered.
- [`Kernel.exit!(code)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exit-21) does the same, but exits immediatelly, no `at_exit` handlers called.
- [`Kernel.abort(message)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-abort) takes a `message` that will be printed to STDERR just before exiting with a failure code=1.

Different values of exit codes are barely suitable for detecting problems and debugging the code. However, they are very simple to use and making the parent process read them is almost trivial. Hence, `exit` and `exit!`.

If you can spend more time and make the error checking more robust, you'll need some serious error messages, not just codes. Traditionally, you can print them to STDERR if it exists. You can print manually to STDERR via normal `puts`, but exit-codes will still be used at the lowest level.

Printing to STDERR does not mark your job automatically as failed, so, `abort` was created to allow you to write and quit easily. A default exit code of 1 is enough to mark the FAIL condition, as it's assumed that all the real contextual information will be included in the error messages provided by you.

Also note that any unhanded exceptions, such as `raise "wtf"` with no `rescue` anywhere, actually behave as if calling `Kernel.abort`: they print to STDERR and use `exitcode=1`.

You said `exit(false)` but the [`exit!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exit-21) documentation says that the parameter is `status code` to be used.

I've just checked that on Windows and Ruby 1.9.3:

```
exit 0       # quits with code: 0
exit 1       # quits with code: 1
exit false   # quits with code: 1
exit true    # quits with code: 0
```

which really surprises me, as I'd assume that `false` would be coerced to `0` in the traditional C way.  So, maybe you should rather be using integers like `0` or `1` to be perfectly clear about what code will be used.

Comment: Can you provide sample examples... with each of your statement... ? Which would make this answer more helpful.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I actually was in the middle of edit'o'writing it :)

Comment: Okay,,, Go ahead then! :-)

Comment: So I figure, `exit` is a general way to terminate a program. `abort` is there if you're going to provide a message along with exit code, and you're fine with exit code `1`. `exit!` allows you to skip `at_exit` handlers. Can't see use case for that though.

Comment: `exit(false)` is a quote from [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-abort), you must be using a simplified version of it. Also, the [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/exit-exit-abort-raise-get-me-outta-here/) you linked says: "There’s a convention in the Unix world that an exit code equal to 0 means that the program was successful. Any other exit code denotes some kind of failure." The same goes for `windows`.

Comment: And it appears "immediately" doesn't mean much in description of `abort`. The one that exits immediately is `exit!`, I take it.

Comment: @x-yuri: (1) `exit/exit!/abort` - yes that's right. (2) `exit(false)` - I know that convention well. Note that `exit` comes from C. Also, `exit(0)` means success and non-zero means failure. In Ruby `exit(N)`, function accepts integers and passes them directly to OS. OK! But, in C,`exit(false)` would end up in exitcode of 0, and `exit(true)` in non-zero, while Ruby it's opposite. I think it's somewhat confusing, that's all. (3) I'm pretty sure that `abort` calls `exit` which raises an exception, a usually unhandled one. OTOH, I think that `exit!` terminates the process by some native func.

Comment: (2) `in C,exit(false) would end up in exitcode of 0, and exit(true) in non-zero` I bet people don't usually pass boolean values to `exit` function, particularly considering there are [`EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` macroses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2425227/52499). Also, passing them in `C` would be confusing, because `exit(false)` results in successful termination of the program. So, `ruby`'s behavior is fine by me. Although, I understand, that people coming from `C` might automatically translate `false` into `0` and get confused. But that's not to be expected of `ruby`.

Comment: (3) Still, with `abort` `at_exit` handlers are executed. So, I believe it's `exit!` that is "immediate", not the other two.

Comment: The reason exit(true) returns 0 is because the program exit status convention of Unix/Linux/Posix is the opposite of the C boolean value convention. "Success" exit status in Posix is 0. Anything non-zero is failure and the value can be optionally used to communicate/distinguish the type of failure. It would be strange if exit(true) meant that your program had failed and exit(false) meant that it had succeeded, even though that more closely follows the C boolean value convention.