# How come params no longer contains the named parameters in BetterError?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am not sure if there was something that changed in Sinatra or one of the gems but when I try to inspect params on a route with named params, it comes out empty. Is this an issue with BetterErrors or something else?

To elaborate, here is the code:

```
class SiteApp < App  

  get '/test/:id' do
    abort asdfasdf
    "Hello ID: #{params[:id]}"
  end

end
```

Then I point my browser to /test/1234 which launches BetterError. 
I expect params to have an id of 1234, but it is empty instead, only contains 'captures' (which is another question, as I'm not even sure where that came from and why).

[image: BetterError params empty]

But strangely, instead of doing 'abort', if I do 'abort asdfasdf', it now displays the params I want to see.

[image: BetterError shows params now]

It always worked fine for me till now just doing 'abort' to check out the params. But now, I need to add some random characters after abort to get the correct params.

Here is a full [screencast](https://jaequery.sfo2.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/misc/Screen%20Recording%202018-10-06%20at%2008.03%20AM%20(1).mov).

The question is, is this a problem with Sinatra? Or Mustermann? Or BetterErrors?

Comment: It's hard to know where in the stack the issue is without reproducing it.  But I would suggest trying out https://github.com/pry as you can really dig through the stack inside a pry console.  Also don't make us download files to watch your screencast, but use a public hosted platform.

Comment: Can you post the the App class code?

Comment: @lacostenycoder: here is the App class, https://pastebin.com/bJwezK6U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `abort` for this purpose as has unpredictable side effect.  Use `raise` instead.  The reason why is that `abort` will kill a process and send a string that you provide to `STDERR`.  This can be useful in simple single process scripts but should be avoided inside of applications, servers, anything where threading can be an issue.  It was not intended for this purpose.  Furthermore, if you want to see what's going on inside your code, I highly recommend using [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) instead.

```
#app.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'better_errors'
require 'pry' #this is recommended but only for development purposes

use BetterErrors::Middleware
BetterErrors.application_root = __dir__
BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '172.0.0.0/0'
bettererrors = true

get '/test/:id' do
  "Hello ID: #{params[:id]}"
  raise 'foo'
end
```

But I would recommend using pry instead:
    get '/test/:id' do
      "Hello ID: #{params[:id]}"
      binding.pry # now you can pry your stack from the ruby console!
    end

Then just run

```
ruby app.rb
# then in browser go to  http://localhost:4567/test/123
# better error opens and params are available
# inside better errors console type
params
#=> {"id"=>"123"}
```

It also works if you do `raise` with no message passed.  Better Errors is supposed to handle exceptions and so use `raise` because `abort` is a way to cancel a ruby script from execution and should not be used for your purpose here.

You can see why by simply testing this from terminal.

```
irb
#now you're in an interactive ruby shell
abort
#now your ruby shell session is over
irb
raise
#RuntimeError with stack trace
```

[See this for more information on commands which kill processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340609/what-is-the-difference-between-exit-and-abort#23340693) see

Comment: hi @lacostenycoder, thanks but can you try just, 'abort' ?   as i mentioned, typing abort and something appended after works. it just doesn't work when it's abort by itself.

Comment: very weird.  Now i'm getting the same behavior you got regardless of what message I type inside abort or even without a message.  I swear it worked when I tried it the first few times. However I updated my answer.

Comment: excellent, this worked! but i still can't explain why abort (w/ no params) worked for me to do what i need this whole time and stopped working recently.