# Ruby ".downcase! " and "downcase" confusion

Tags: ruby

I just started Ruby programming. I had read [Difference Between downcase and downcase! in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709229/difference-between-downcase-and-downcase-in-ruby). However I encounter an interesting problem in practice, here is code:

```
a = "lower"
a = a.downcase
print a

Compiler return: lower
```

However if I try:

```
a = "lower"
a = a.downcase!
print a

Compiler return: nil
```

However, both version of code returns "lower" if "a = LOWER"

Comment: What is `Compiler`? What is the question?

Answer (score 10):

> downcase! → str or nil
>
> Downcases the contents of str, **returning nil if no changes were made**. Note: case replacement is effective only in ASCII region.

Documentation: [String#downcase!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-downcase-21)

Comment: You get my vote for linking to the manual, which clearly wasn't read.

Answer (score 7):

a.downcase! modifies "a"  directly -- you do not need to assign the result to "a".

```
1.9.3p362 :003 > a = "A"
 => "A" 
1.9.3p362 :004 > a.downcase!
 => "a" 
1.9.3p362 :005 > puts a
a
 => nil 
1.9.3p362 :006 > a = "A"
 => "A" 
1.9.3p362 :007 > a.downcase
 => "a" 
1.9.3p362 :008 > puts a
A
 => nil
```

The danger of assigning variable = variable.downcase! is that if variable is already downcase then you have just set the variable to nil -- probably not your intent.

```
1.9.3p362 :001 > variable = 'a'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 => "a"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
1.9.3p362 :002 > variable = variable.downcase!
 => nil                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
1.9.3p362 :003 > puts variable                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

 => nil
```

Answer (score 2):

`downcase!` is a method which modifies the string in-place (whereas `downcase` creates a new string instance).

The return value of `downcase!` is `nil` if the string has not been modified, or the new modified string. In the latter case the string in `a` gets overwritten. The correct way of using `downcase!` is:

```
a = "LOWER"
a.downcase! # no assignment to a here
print a # prints "lower", the original "LOWER" is lost
```

And for `downcase`:

```
a = "LOWER"
print a.downcase # a is still "LOWER", but "lower" gets printed
```

As a general rule of thumb: If a methods ends with `!`, the method overwrites values or modifies state in your variables.

Additionally in your case:

```
print "lower".downcase! # prints nil, because "lower" is already written in lower case
```

Comment: There's no void type. And `downcase!` can return strings

Comment: Thanks, I find your explanation very helpful

Answer (score 1):

downcase! will return nil if no changes were made.
You can check it with `ri downcase!`